# Should I send the report during a control request in?

Tags: usb, hid

I'm building a USB keyboard using the HID protocol.

I have been said that, in case of a control-in where the request type is `0x01`, I am supposed to reply with the last report. That means that I would have to write the reports both to:

- the USB endpoint,
- when there is a control-in request.

I do not do that: I only write the report to the endpoint, and I ignore all the control-in requests, excepting the one asking for the report descriptor. My keyboard works perfectly well, both on Linux (Fedora, Android) and Windows. I don't own a Mac, so I couldn't test on one.

My questions are:

- Does the spec really ask for the device to send the reports twice, the second times being during a control-in request?
- If yes, can I safely ignore that part, because it seems that it works well without it?

Comment: The spec is available for you to read. "This request is mandatory and must be supported by all devices."

Comment: @hobbs Then why does my keyboard work when I ignore it? And it works on totally different OSes.

Comment: Also, it's super weird: the host already has the report. What is the need to get it a second time?

Comment: Sorry to say this, but I don't think Super User is the correct site for this question. I'm not sure there is a correct site at all.

Comment: @DanielB I think they migrated my question because it's more a software one (I guess?) since it's about the protocol.